# Python multiprocessing throws error when passing array argument

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to setup a unit testing tool that starts up several instances of a function that runs concurrently using python multiprocessing.

My main thread looks like this. The function new_instance() takes an object returned by the get_landing_pages() function.

If I pass a simple string in as the argument, the new process starts fine. But when I try to pass the lp object I get a big dump of errors.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lp = get_landing_pages()
    p1 = Process(target=new_instance,args=(lp,))
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target=new_instance,args=(lp,))
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

A portion of the errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\cory_weiner\Desktop\dashboardErrorTool 6-30-2016.py", line 118, in <module>
        p1.start()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start
        self._popen = Popen(self)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__
        dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump
        ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump
        self.save(obj)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
        save(state)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
        self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
        save(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 554, in save_tuple
        save(element)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
        self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 639, in _batch_appends
        save(x)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
        save(state)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
        self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
        save(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
        save(state)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
        self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
        save(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
        save(state)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
        self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
        save(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
        save(state)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
        self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
        save(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
        save(state)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
        self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
        save(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
        save(state)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
        self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
        save(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
        save(state)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
        self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
        save(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
        save(state)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
        self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
        save(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
        save(state)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
        self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
        save(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
        save(state)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save
        f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 655, in save_dict
        self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 687, in _batch_setitems
        save(v)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save
        self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 425, in save_reduce
```

Comment: You left out the most important part of the traceback, the actual error.

Comment: Possibly what you have inside the array is not pickle-able. Can you show your get_landing_pages() stuff? Some stuff that are not pickle-able are nested classes, and I/O objects.